# Cron job once in three days

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cron

In linux ec2 instance i want to run a cron job 3 Days once to automate a process once in three days as a sudo user in my linux ec2 instance.

Can anyone help me out with the cron.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron that executes 3 days of the week and once you finish these three days delete it it.

```
$ crontab -e
```

And add the following line:

```
* * * * 1-3 sudo <your comand>
```

These is an explanation of the cron syntax:

```
 ┌────────── minute (0 - 59)
 │ ┌──────── hour (0 - 23)
 │ │ ┌────── day of month (1 - 31)
 │ │ │ ┌──── month (1 - 12)
 │ │ │ │ ┌── day of week (0 - 6 => Sunday - Saturday, or
 │ │ │ │ │                1 - 7 => Monday - Sunday)
 ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
 * * * * * command to be executed
```

And you can use the number of the days or the short name of the days:

```
0 - Sun      Sunday
1 - Mon      Monday
2 - Tue      Tuesday
3 - Wed      Wednesday
4 - Thu      Thursday
5 - Fri      Friday
6 - Sat      Saturday
7 - Sun      Sunday
```

Comment: Ginerama, But this cron i checked this one, It has the capability to At every minute on every day-of-week from Monday through Wednesday

Comment: Of course, sorry. `0 1 * * 1-3 sudo <your comand>` . Now it's executed once at 01:00 AM from Monday to Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
0 0 */3 * * sudo ...
\_/ \_/ | |
 |   |  | Every week 
 |   |  |
 |   |  Every month
 |   |
 |   Every third day
 |
 Midnight
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Comment: This one i checked this one will run At 00:00 on every 3rd day-of-month